# CSS サイズの揃わないli要素を複数行/不等分で並べる

Tags: css

サイズの揃わない画像を下の数字のような並びにしたいです。
指定された１行にある数が３個・４個・２個と決まっていないので、うまく並べられません。

１　　２　　３　　
　　４　５　６　７　　
　　　８　　　９

flexのspace-aroundできれいに並ぶかと思ったのですが、レスポンシブ指定のため拡縮で１行にある数が変化してしまいます。(拡縮で画像間の余白が変化するデザインです)
li要素のため、１行ずつをspan等で囲んだり、brで改行するわけにもいかず１行に収まる画像の数を指定できないのですが、どうするべきでしょうか。
適切な方法をご教授ください。

```
<ul class="list-img">
    <li class="img"></li>
    <li class="img"></li>
    <li class="img"></li>
    <li class="img"></li>
    <li class="img"></li>
    <li class="img"></li>
    <li class="img"></li>
    <li class="img"></li>
    <li class="img"></li>
</ul>


.list-img{
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    .img{
        display: inline-block;
    }
}
```

Comment: 表示領域全体のサイズやPortrait/Landscapeが変わっても、3段で3個,4個,2個のレイアウトは変えたくない、ということでしょうか？

Comment: ”表示領域全体のサイズやPortrait/Landscapeが変わっても、3段で3個,4個,2個のレイアウトは変えたくない、ということでしょうか？”
そのとおりです。質問が分かりづらくて申し訳ありません。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

例えばリストを入れ子にするのはどうでしょう？
合計した横幅がウインドウをはみ出した場合とか、各段の間の空白の考慮とかを入れていませんが、以下のような感じで。
li の中の数字はダミーで入れています。

```
<ul class="list-row">
  <li>
    <ul class="list-column">
      <li class="img">１</li>
      <li class="img">２</li>
      <li class="img">３</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ul class="list-column">
      <li class="img">４</li>
      <li class="img">５</li>
      <li class="img">６</li>
      <li class="img">７</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ul class="list-column">
      <li class="img">８</li>
      <li class="img">９</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

.list-row{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}
.list-column{
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    .img{
        display: inline-block;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

bootstrapを使っていいのでした。

```html
<li class="img col-sm-4"></li>
<li class="img col-sm-4"></li>
<li class="img col-sm-4"></li>
<li class="img col-sm-3"></li>
<li class="img col-sm-3"></li>
<li class="img col-sm-3"></li>
<li class="img col-sm-3"></li>
<li class="img col-sm-6"></li>
<li class="img col-sm-6"></li>
```